# I am getting [object MediaError] while playing audio in html5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am getting [object MediaError] while playing audio in html5 audio tag

I console the audio tag with code as below

```
myAudio.error.code
```

It displays 4 in console log.

Any one can assist me why I am getting this error. Even my audio tag is as below.

```
<audio id="scamper_music_sting_SFX" src="lib/game15/sounds/language/english/scamper_music_sting_SFX.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

path is correct.

Comment: What is the MIME type returned by the server?

Comment: Hi Qantas , how can I display or get MIME type that is return from server.?

Comment: Hi Qantas, I found Content-Type equal to audio/mpeg

Comment: Just making sure that you're looking at the right one, could you place a screenshot and edit your question to attach that in?

Comment: Unable to attach screen shot, but here is the network content for the mp3 file

URL Method Result Type Received Taken Initiator Wait‎‎ Start‎‎ Request‎‎ Response‎‎ Cache read‎‎ Gap‎‎
/vss/CCI_UX/lib/game15/sounds/language/english/scamper_music_sting_SFX.mp3 GET 304 audio/mpeg 210 B < 1 ms  5023 0 0 0 0 5601

Comment: Content-Type is actually audio/mpeg

Comment: Browser? There isn't enough information to answer  your question.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some permission issues on the folder structure your audio file is in, you can test by moving the audio file into the same directory as your html file. Then test with the audio element below.

```
<audio id="scamper_music_sting_SFX" src="scamper_music_sting_SFX.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
```